# How to handle big database?

Tags: sql, bigdata

I have a database with over million users, each user has enormous amount of data stored.

Needless to say, the performance has decayed.

(Each user has its own website and CMS)

How do I handle the database for many users?

I herd an idea of **saving each user information as its own database**, instead of tables with foreign keys.

What are your thoughts of this idea? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

What other ways should I be considering?

Comment: Please clarify _saving each user information as its own database_

Comment: A million users hardly qualifies as "big data". What exactly do you think an "enormous amount of data" is? tens or even hundreds million of rows is not considered big nowadays let alone "enormous"

Comment: MongoDB is web scale.

Comment: "big data".

When each user has on his website a chat.
Each chat itself consists of over 100k + messages.
Consider 100 million rows in a table just to show chat history of a specific user.

Answer (score 1):

One million users with referenced data is not big data.

If the performance is bad then you might have a look at your SQL code or front-end code.

Use indexes also to increase the Query Execution time. Most of the times indexes and optimization of the code is the trick. A lot of other things also plays a big role like your CPU, memory disk etc.

I would first have a look at the code and see if you can optimize anything and then if that doesn't help then seperate the data in multiple databases.

Even if you do this you might still have problem with performance if the databases is hosted on the same server.

Good luck!